# WP login check before creating new pages or acessing plugin

Tags: wordpress, passwords

I am new to wordpress.

In WP Admin panel I want to check login once again before creating new pages/plugins/custom admin pages.

I searched a lot but didn't get any useful info. So I want to know is there any plugin or function available or I need to do it manually?

Comment: Yes I know we can't create pages without Admin login but still I want to do this functionality for some few inbuilt and some custom sensible pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
include_once 'wp-config.php';
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
 // Display WordPress login form:
   $args = array(
    'redirect' => Username custom redirect location, 
    'form_id' => 'loginform-custom',
    'label_username' => __( 'Username custom text' ),
    'label_password' => __( 'Password custom text' ),
    'label_remember' => __( 'Remember Me custom text' ),
    'label_log_in' => __( 'Log In custom text' ),
    'remember' => true
);
wp_login_form( $args );
}
?>
```

As per @go4gory's suggestion.
Ref : [Customizing_the_Login_Form](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form)

Answer (score 0):

Jaydeep -

Wordpress has built in function to check whether user is logged in or not.

For example:

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo 'Welcome, registered user!';
} else {
    echo 'Welcome, visitor!';
}
?>
```

[Click](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in) to get more information.

If the above is not pertinent, feel free to ignore it. And do let me know more about your problem.

Comment: Yes that I know but I want recheck User Name and password after wp-admin login...
like before creating new post admin user must need to add user name & password

Comment: I got your point.As per my assumption you can achieve this by creating page meta(For username and password). And display message on header that please enter your username and password before creating new page. At the time of publish button click, add save post action to check whether username and password inserted by admin user is correct or not.